# My code is returning 0 instead of the correct number

Tags: c

It is was saying the user is 0 seconds old and has eaten 0 oreos despite those functions being almost identical to others that work.

I have tried changing it per the comments but now everything is returning as zero.

This is for a homework assignment in basic C and I am just trying to fix this code in the simplest way possible, thank you in advance! :)

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int ComputeUserDays(int userAgeYears) {
   int userAgeDays;

   userAgeDays = userAgeYears * 365;
   userAgeDays = userAgeDays + (userAgeYears / 4);

   return userAgeDays;
   }
int ComputeUserMinutes(int userAgeDays) {
   int userAgeMinutes;

   userAgeMinutes = userAgeDays * 24 * 60;

   return userAgeMinutes;
   }
int ComputeUserSeconds(int userAgeMinutes) {
   int userAgeSeconds;

   userAgeSeconds = userAgeMinutes * 60;

   return userAgeSeconds;
   } 
int ComputeUserSneezes(int userAgeDays) {
   int userAgeSneezes;

   userAgeSneezes = userAgeDays * 4;

   return userAgeSneezes;
   } 
int ComputeUserCalories(int userAgeDays) {
   int userCalories;

   userCalories = userAgeDays * 2000;

   return userCalories;
   } 
int ComputeUserOreos(int userCalories) {
   int userOreos;

   userOreos = userCalories / 45;

   return userOreos;
   } 

int main(void) {
   int userAgeYears; 
   int userAgeDays = ComputeUserDays(userAgeYears);
   int userAgeMinutes = ComputeUserMinutes(userAgeDays);
   int userAgeSeconds = ComputeUserSeconds(userAgeMinutes);
   int userCalories = ComputeUserCalories(userAgeDays);
   int userSneezes =  ComputeUserSneezes(userAgeDays);
   int userOreos = ComputeUserOreos(userCalories);

   printf("Enter your age in years: ");

   scanf("%d", &userAgeYears);

   printf("You are %d days old.\n", userAgeDays );

   printf("You are %d minutes old.\n", userAgeMinutes );

   printf("You are %d seconds old.\n", userAgeSeconds );

   printf("You have sneezed %d times in your life.\n", userSneezes );

   printf("You have expended %d calories in your life.\n", userCalories );

   printf("You needed to eat %d Oreos to expend those calories.\n", userOreos );


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have not initialised `int userCalories;` (and others) so the number of Oreos needed is undefined. Assign values to your variables from the return values of the functions.

Comment: Also, Weather Vane, I do not know what that means. I have only been taking this class for three weeks and it's only taught through Zybooks. How do I assign valued to my variables?

Comment: You need to call your functions after you have read the Age of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your logic to:

```
   int userAgeYears; 
   printf("Enter your age in years: ");
   scanf("%d", &userAgeYears);
   int userAgeDays = ComputeUserDays(userAgeYears);
   int userAgeMinutes = ComputeUserMinutes(userAgeDays);
   int userCalories = ComputeUserCalories(userAgeDays);


   printf("You are %d days old.\n", userAgeDays );

   printf("You are %d minutes old.\n",  userAgeMinutes );
   .
   .
   .
```

and so on.

Because you are not refreshing your variables, you are just calling the functions without refreshing it.